# PrimeNg p-checkbox preselection without model

Tags: angular5, primeng

I'm trying to iterate an array and present it as checkboxs so that the user can later check/uncheck them
I'm not sure how to make the checkbox be preselected since i have an Array of items
but i'm iterating an internal array

so far i have this

```
      <div *ngFor="let privilege of group.privileges" style="text-align:left">
        <div class="ui-g-4">
          <p-checkbox label="{{privilege.privilegeName}}" [(ngModel)]="{{privilege.show <-- this is not working of course}}" name="fixco-privileges-view" value="{{privilege.privilegeName}}"></p-checkbox>
        </div>
      </div>
```

the checkbox and their label are appearing nice but not preselected...

Answer (score 0):

If `show` property of a privilege is a boolean, just add `binary="true"` to your `p-checkbox`.

Also, remove the square braces in `[(ngModel)]="{{privilege.show}}"`.

So your HTML code becomes

```
<p-checkbox binary="true" label="{{privilege.privilegeName}}" [(ngModel)]="privilege.show" name="fixco-privileges-view" value="{{privilege.privilegeName}}"></p-checkbox>
```

See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hODmkqQcpb2xu4kNLv5i?p=preview)